# SQL DELETE WHERE GROUP BY ... HAVING

Tags: sql, sql-server

Would there be a way to make this SQL statement to work? Here's the code:

```
DELETE AHsTransactions
WHERE SerialNumber <> 0
GROUP BY TypeID, AH1ID, AH2ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP', so seems impossible in just one SQL statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to alter that SQL statement to work directly.

Probably the nearest equivalent that does work is below

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TypeID, AH1ID, AH2ID) AS c
         FROM   AHsTransactions
         WHERE  SerialNumber <> 0)
DELETE FROM T
WHERE  c > 1
```

(compatible with SQL Server 2005+)

Comment: Very cool :)   Too bad there's nothing in MySql for it, but good to know while we're still using SQL Server!